# Ubuntu (14.10, 14.04) Graphics rendering issues with nvidia 331, 346 when using two screens at once (built in and external)

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, graphics, hdmi

I bought a new dell laptop ( inspiron 15 3000 series ) with 2 gb nvidia geforce 117m. It shipped with ubuntu 14.04. That was very choppy and slow. I installed nvidia 346.47 ( from the nvidia website). This caused my lightdm to stop working. 
Next time i tried the same thing and my screen froze. I did a hard reboot and that caused boot drive not get recognized.

Then I installed 14.10. This time followed [this reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549553/ubuntu-stuck-after-login-when-i-install-nvidia-driver). 
I still have the same issues. My text looks like this.
[image].

The output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux prakhar-Inspiron-3543 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 17:56:17 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT 1 (Narrowed Down the problem after further inquiry)**

This happens when I attach my laptop to a external screen using a HDMI port.

**EDIT 2 (Narrowed down further)**

Everything works fine when single screen is active (either one of them)... not able to get them to work together. The result is same as the image.

Comment: Ubuntu ships with its own Nvidia drivers. Use those. And X drivers should not affect `lightdm`.

Comment: I tried installing from Ubuntu store , ppa, nvidia official.... All of them caused the graphics to be rendered like that in the photo above... @Faheem Mitha

Comment: Can you post a link to your xorg log, please?

Comment: Also, the `xorg.conf`, while you are about it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZhbqX4fc for xorg log... @Farheem

Comment: Couldnt localte xorg.conf. ran a find command and couldnt locate anywhere... not in /etc/X11/ too..

Comment: Well, the xorg.conf must be somewhere, since your log is reporting that it is looking for the nvidia module, and then failing to find it. Run `find . -name 'xorg.conf'` inside `/etc/X11`. The file would normally be `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Also, post `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` , in the question, not as a paste. Also please give the results of `uname -a`.

Comment: Also, it seems to be loading nouveau, i.e. `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so`.

Comment: dpkg -l | grep nvidia shows nothing...

Comment: Oh, if you have a local installation it wouldn't. But regardless, your local installation is not working, since nvidia is not being found. I suggest you switch back to the official binary drivers.

Comment: My computer stops working when i install them.... what do think the problem is??... I was wondering if this is a faulty graphics card...

Comment: Well, that is unlikely to be the fault of the official binary drivers. And switching to a local installation is also unlikely to help. Yes, it might be faulty hardware.

Comment: @FaheemMitha i narrowed down the problem.... i got my laptop checked ... the gpu seems to be fine... could you suggest something... drivers installed are nvidia-340 on 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working for both screens. I didnt read the xorg log carefully enough. Noveau was being loaded along with nvidia and intel drivers. And it might be that the priority for noveau was higher. 
I did a complete uninstall of noveau and didnt install any driver apart form nvidia-340. That makes ubuntu graphics stable.

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

I found this package name from the answer provided for this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412141/uninstall-nouveau). Thanks a lot to user224082 for the answer.

Comment: Removing `nouveau` should not be necessary. If you really don't have an xorg file, you could add one just specifying you want to use the `nvidia` driver.

Comment: i couldnt locate the xorg.conf then. I took a second look just now... it is there... i cant explain this behavior ... any reason you could think this might happen...

Comment: Could you post the `xorg.conf` into your question? Just curious. Can you think of anything you might have done to generate the `xorg.conf`?

Comment: nothing apart from updates performed on my system after that purge....

Comment: xorg.conf    http://pastebin.com/psFQWW8g

Comment: Ypur `xorg.conf` listed both `nvidia` and `intel` as drivers. While I'm no expert, I think this is a bad idea. I recommend you take out the intel. Save the original file as backup in the unlikely event that X insists on having both present.

Answer (score 0):

Hi unfortunately in linux you can only use one driver at a time, as its loaded from the kernel (when using kms) and loaded using modules compiled for the running kernel.
I see you trying to load both Intel and NVIDIA(nouveau) drivers at the same time. which will not work.

For the two displays to work at the same time you have to use either vesa or fbdev drivers as they can use both cards at the same time. but the perfromance will be sloppy as use have noticed.

Comment: I have installed drivers for both... But have been switching gpus to see which one performs... In my case none do...

Comment: I'm using dell lattitude E6530 which uses the same(INTEL) drivers for both ports. maybe there is something that must be done in bios (or uefi). maybe try testing the section for graphic because from the Xorg.log in paste bin it shows that your are loading two different drivers. which is weired for a laptop.

Comment: can you run lspci -k, and provide the results.

Comment: lspci -k http://pastebin.com/z4LmT6hc ... which binary drivers are you talking about